# Issue with copying array having string index jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to copy an array `ar` which contains string indexes, to another array  `arCopy` using jquery. The array looks like shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/odresmfg/). Initially I tried by copying arrays like:

```
var arCopy = ar;
```

But when I try to add a new value to array `arCopy`, it got inserted in `ar` also. So I tried with `slice` :

```
var ar = [];
ar['color'] = ['red', 'blue'];
var arCopy = ar.slice();
ar['color'].push("kk");
arCopy['color'].push("kk");
console.log(ar); // outputs red,blue,kk,kk
```

But `slice` is also pushing values to original array `ar`. Is this because I'm using array with string index?

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because `arCopy` is still a reference to the original `ar`.

Comment: `var arCopy = ar;`  Is not a copy.  It's just an assignment.  Both arCopy and ar will point to the same element in memory.

Comment: No, `slice` works.  We can't help you if all you state is "not working"

Comment: ^ https://jsfiddle.net/2uxf5a0d/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is *not* a duplicate, since he's saying `ar.slice()` doesn't work

Comment: @GeorgeJempty `slice()` works absolutely fine, and this question is worthless without knowing the OPs exact circumstance. However I've reopened the question in the hopes that the OP will update it with more useful information.

Comment: @Jenz I placed your code sample in an executable snippet. It does not output `red,blue,kk,kk` - but that's because you're not using the array in a valid manner. Are you getting arrays an objects confused?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. No the array in this code is not an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

this is what your code do

```
var ar = []; //create empty Array "ar"
ar['color'] = ['red', 'blue']; //adding an array on 'color' parameter
var arCopy = ar.slice(); //cloning(copy) array "ar" on arCopy

arCopy = ar;//make arCopy and ar the same object (remember that Array inherits from object)
ar['color'].push("kk");//adding "kk" to ar (and arCopy because now is the same object)
arCopy['color'].push("kk");//adding "kk" to arCopy (and ar because now is the same object)
console.log(ar); // outputs red,blue,kk,kk
```

**UPDATE**

you can use objects as array but u can't use arrays as objects so you cant add an argument on arrays, only values

```
var ar = {}; 
ar.color = ['red', 'blue'];
var arCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ar));
ar['color'].push("kk1");
arCopy['color'].push("kk2");
console.log(ar); // outputs {"color":["red","blue","kk1"]}
console.log(arCopy); // outputs {"color":["red","blue","kk2"]}
```

> slice() definition:
>
> The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new
>   array object.
>
> The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start
>   argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

Comment: I deleted that line, but still slice() is giving empty array.

Comment: ok you are using an array object as a object and that is not the way you should do that

Answer (score 0):

copy the array  by using

```
arCopy = ar['color'].slice();
```

it will copy the array created inside your array to the respective array